# Tensorflow - porting a modified MNIST example into Android

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

The following is the CNN model function I use to generate the Neural Network I'm about to use:

```
def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
  """Model function for CNN."""
  x = features["x"]
  input_layer = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 64, 64, 3])

  # The rest of the CNN goes here, utilizing input_layer as the input for the conv1 layer, similar to the MNIST handwritten digits example except with more conv-pool layers and eight classes
```

Put simply, I want to train this in the PC using Python and make sure this is Android compatible, and that means feeding the proceeding frozen `graph.pb` into 
the `TensorFlowInferenceInterface`.

In the Android part I've used:

```
private float[] getPixels(Mat img, double mean, double std){
    int inputSize = 64;
    int channels = 3;
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputSize, inputSize, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(img, bmp);
    int[] intValues = new int[inputSize * inputSize];
    bmp.getPixels(intValues, 0, inputSize, 0, 0, inputSize, inputSize);

    float[] floatValues = new float[inputSize * inputSize * channels];
    for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
        final int val = intValues[i];
        floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = (float)(((double)(((val >> 16) & 0xFF)) - mean) / std);
        floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = (float)(((double)(((val >> 8) & 0xFF)) - mean) / std);
        floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = (float)(((double)((val & 0xFF)) - mean) / std);
    }

    return floatValues;
}
```

to retrieve the flattened pixels from the OpenCV Mat I want to feed into the TFII with this call:

```
tfii.feed("enqueue_input/random_shuffle_queue", getPixels(colorResizedSubmat, mu.get(0, 0)[0], sigma.get(0, 0)[0]), 1, 64, 64, 3);
```

But all I got is an exception, saying:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'RandomShuffleQueueV2' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels: <no registered kernels>

[[Node: enqueue_input/random_shuffle_queue = RandomShuffleQueueV2[capacity=1000, component_types=[DT_INT64, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT], container="", min_after_dequeue=250, seed=1, seed2=4, shapes=[[], [], [64,64,3]], shared_name=""]()]]
```

I've searched everywhere for this issue, and the only clue I got is x being a `tf.Placeholder()` instead of a dictionary, and I don't think I can change it into a Placeholder because I'm using a `numpy_input_fn`, and I'm not even sure the cnn_model_fn even runs in a `tf.Session()`.

How do I solve this?

EDIT: Is it possible to even solve it without rewriting the entire thing without using the Estimator API?

Comment: There's a [similar issue on Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9476)

Comment: I'm currently using the tensorflow-android gradle build. Should I build from source?

Comment: No clue. Android tensorflow is a blindspot for me, I know ANdroid and I know TensorFlow, but not the TF Android API. If you google the first line of the exception you'll find 5 results where 4 are Github issues, some of those should work (even though it's a different call in most of the cases).